# FuelPHP ORM bulk update related objects

Tags: orm, fuelphp

I am trying to bulk update a table full of related items on an invoice.

```
$_POST           Existing relations   intended result
=====================================================
                 item_id: 3           unlink 3
item_id: 4       item_id: 4           update 4
item_id: 5       item_id: 5           update 5
item_id: null                         create x
item_id: null                         create x
```

I am pushing a json array of objects that have all of the `$_properties` the `Model` expects.

My Controller method looks like this:

```
public function update_items($invoice_id) 
{
    $invoice = Model_Invoice::find($invoice_id);

    if ($items = MyInput::json())
    {
        $invoice->from_array(array('invoice_items' => $items));
    }

    $invoice->save();
}
```

This gives a PK Collision error when saving the Related objects (invoice_items).
This is because the objects that have been updated in the `$invoice->invoice_items` are all `is_new() == true`.

How should I be structuring this code? I don't want to have to manage add/edit/delete states for every incoming related item.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an update, make sure you fetch the items to be updated:

`$invoice = Model_Invoice::find($invoice_id, array('related' => array('invoice_items')));`

Comment: If I fetch first, it will not delete the records which are not part of the POST. This is part of the issue, since I want to bulk replace the complete data set, except for the items in the POST AND in the existing object, which should get updated.

Comment: I should add I am currently doing it "manually" - looping through both sets for matches, performing updates, deleting unmatched records, and then another loop to insert incoming records. It just seems like this should work... :)

Comment: You'll have to make a diff between what is stored and what is posted, no way around that. Fetch the invoice object with all related item objects, loop over them and delete/unset any not present in the post, then loop over your post to update/create.